# Dragging/moving multiple geojsons on leaflet-geoman

Tags: leaflet, geojson, leaflet-geoman

I'd like to move/drag geojson features on map so that the distance to each other stays the same.

Choose geojsons by clicking them and then dragging them together. How should I make this?

Thanks!

I read about syncLayersOnDrag but can not get it to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `syncLayersOnDrag` after adding the layer, it works

```
// data are coming from smaple-geojson.js
const geoLayer = L.geoJSON([bicycleRental, campus]).addTo(map)
map.fitBounds(geoLayer.getBounds())

map.pm.setGlobalOptions({
    syncLayersOnDrag: true
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zba1ogjL/

Comment: That was it!! Thank you so much @Falke Design